# Populate radio buttons from an sql database php

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I would like a checkbox with the text populated by the sql database then stored in ajax.

How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming MYSQL as the database type, [check this article](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql)!

Comment: There are any code have you get?

Comment: Are you trying to populate radio buttons or checkboxes?

Comment: Hi, i thought checkboxes / radio buttons were the same, if not then checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generating radio buttons in php should be something like the following:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, value FROM mytable");

//I assume the 2nd entry in the database is the value name and the 3th is the button value
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$row[1].'" value="'.$row[2].'" />'.$row[1];
}
?>
```

The storing in AJAX part is a bit confusing. AJAX is a way of doing a subpage request. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

So if you want to store with ajax you have to build a PHP page which receives the data and puts it in the database. The easiest way to do this is posting the entire form with the data via an ajax request. [Check it out here](http://www.jstiles.com/Blog/How-To-Submit-a-Form-with-jQuery-and-AJAX). Good luck with your endeavors!